# pagination issue on view blocks

Tags: paging

I have 3 view blocks on my page which show a list of blogs(nodes) with a pager. The issue is that whenever I click the 'next' or any link on the pager, all the blocks change, not just the one Im clicking on. Is there some option which unties the paging from the other blocks??

Comment: No problem. Duplicates happen, it took me a while to find that older post - and I **knew** it already. No surprise you might miss it. Of course try better next time ;) but nothing to be really sorry about now.